# Error in AVX loop vectorization

Tags: c++, memory-management, vectorization, intrinsics, avx

When I try to get data with AVX, I get runtime error - **Segmentation fault:**

```
int i = 0;
const int sz = 9;
size_t *src1 = (size_t *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(size_t), 32);
size_t *src2 = (size_t *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(size_t), 32);
size_t *dst  = (size_t *)_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(size_t), 32);


__m256 buffer  = _mm256_load_si256(&src1[i]);
__m256 buffer2 = _mm256_load_si256(&src2[i+1]); //Segmentation fault in this line

//Something...

_mm256_store_si256(dst[i], buffer);


_mm_free(src1);
_mm_free(src2);
_mm_free(dst);
```

I solve the problem by using the ***'_mm256_loadu_si256'*** intrinsic instead. Someone knows why does this happens?

Comment: If your buffers are a small constant size, don't `malloc` them!  Declare them as local arrays.  In C99, or GNU C++, variable-length local arrays are efficient, too, as long as you know the size will be small enough to not exhaust the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_mm*_load_*` intrinsics work only with *aligned* data, whereas the `_mm*_loadu_*` intrinsics allow you to work with *unaligned* data (at a performance penalty).

The segmentation fault is telling you that the values you're trying to load from memory into the AVX register are not aligned on the proper boundary. For the 256-bit version, the values must be aligned on a 32-byte boundary.

If you don't want to pay the performance penalty of loading unaligned values, then you need to make sure that the values are properly aligned on 32-byte boundaries. You can do this either by inserting padding or using an annotation that forces alignment. The annotations are compiler-specific—on GCC, you would use something like `__attribute__((aligned(32)))`, whereas on MSVC, you'd use something like `__declspec(align(32))`.

The problem *here*, though, is that your array-indexing on the second load is forcing a load from an unaligned memory location. That can't be solved by an attribute/annotation. You're going to have to pad the values out. Using `size_t` as a pointer type is probably the first mistake. That type should be 32-bytes wide.

Comment: But I am properly aligning on 32-byte boundaries with `_mm_malloc(sz*sizeof(size_t), 32);` That is why I do not understand what is happening.

Comment: Just updated my answer. That's why your first load works fine. The second load doesn't, though, because you're incrementing the first location by `sizeof(size_t)`, which is not a multiple of 32-bytes.

Comment: Since C++11 there exists *alignas specifier* which allows specifying alignment requirements in a standard way. For example: `alignas(128) char data[32]` will align the data array in memory to 128 bytes.

Comment: `loadu` has full performance when used on data that is aligned.  So when data is almost always aligned, just use `loadu` instead of slowing down the aligned case with extra handling for the rare cases where it's unaligned.  This is a good way to take advantage of the good hardware support for unaligned loads: They're not so expensive that you need to slow down the aligned case to avoid them.

Comment: @peter Thanks for mentioning that. I actually didn't know that. I figured you paid a handling penalty just for using the unaligned versions. Impressive that the designers were able to full off that stunt. Has that *always* been the case, or do you know? (In other words, is your statement only true with respect to AVX, or does it go all the way back to the earliest generation of SSE?)

Comment: @CodyGray: From Agner Fog's insn tables:  The first gen of Intel CPU to have "free" `movups` / `movdqu` was Nehalem.  Core2 (merom and wolfdale) have 1uop aligned loads/stores, but 4uop / 9uop unaligned loads/stores (with one half or third the throughput).  AMD had no penalty for loads in K10, but half throughput for unaligned stores.  Bulldozer-family has no penalty for unaligned loads/stores.  (**In all cases, these numbers are for unaligned ops on aligned data**.  When unaligned ops are expensive, they might not slow down more on misaligned data without cacheline or pageline splits, IDK.)